# Why there are no Android 5.0 SDK samples?

Tags: android

Why there are no Android 5.0 SDK samples? I can't find them in the SDK manager in the Android Studio. There is the SDK and everything but no samples. For 4.x there are samples.

Comment: yes I noticed this too, probably because its not officially release yet i would guess

Comment: they are listed on the [Android developer portal](http://developer.android.com/samples/new/index.html), and all available on Github

Comment: @panini Ah, thanks. I can accept this as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some samples listed on the [Android developer portal](http://developer.android.com/samples/new/index.html), which cover the new APIs introduced in the 5.0 Lollipop release

The page mentions that they should be available through the SDK manager under the L Developer Preview if you prefer to get them from there

> The following code samples were recently published for the L Developer Preview. You can download them in the Android SDK Manager under the SDK Samples component for the L Developer Preview.